# Starting multiple Kafka listeners in Spring Kafka?

Tags: spring-kafka

One of our dev teams is doing something I've never seen before.

First they're defining an abstract class for their consumers.

```
public abstract class KafkaConsumerListener {
    protected void processMessage(String xmlString) {
       
    }
}
```

Then they use 10 classes like the one below to create 10 individual consumers.

```
@Component
public class <YouNameIt>Consumer extends KafkaConsumerListener {

    private static final String <YouNameIt> = "<YouNameIt>";

    @KafkaListener(topics = "${my-configuration.topicname}",
            groupId = "${my-configuration.topicname.group-id}",
            containerFactory = <YouNameIt>)
    public void listenToStuff(@Payload String message) {
        processMessage(message);
    }   
}
```

So with this they're trying to start 10 Kafka listeners (one class/object per listener). Each listener should have own consumer group (with own name) and consume from one (but different) topic.

They seem to use different `ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactories`, each with `@Bean` annotation so they can assign different `groupId` to each container factory.

Is something like that supported by Spring Kafka?

It seems that it worked until few days ago and now it seems that one consumer group gets stuck all the time. It starts, reads few records and then it hangs, the consumer lag is getting bigger and bigger

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is supported, but it's not necessary to create multiple factories just to change the group id - the `groupId` property on the annotation overrides the factory property.

Problems like the one you describe is most likely the consumer thread is "stuck" in user code someplace; take a thread dump to see what the thread is doing.